# API to export cert

Tags: windows, api, certification, application-software-testing

Is there any windows api available to export my cert MMC.exe, which exports the .cer files from their certificate store? I'm looking for the API which is compatible with software testing such as winium/selenium/eclipse IDE. If not programatically how to achieve this?

Comment: What is your particular issue? Why do you need to export it from a store and how are you going to use exported cert with selenium?

Comment: software testing to ensure the certs are exported out. i'm using wininum library in eclipse so i am posting a question here

Comment: You could create PowerShell snippet (see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/export-certificate?view=win10-ps ) and invoke it from automation test suite.